# Laptop screen remains off

Tags: display

The backlight inverter in my laptop blew, so I replaced the screen (by one with a higher resolution). The new screen is properly  detected in Windows (8), but remains off, regardless of `extend` or `duplicate` settings. I've tested this by connecting another vga monitor. Is the new monitor faulty, or am I missing something obvious?

Laptop model: `a52jb`, which is effectivly the `k52jb`. Previous lcd panel: `N156B6-L04`, replaced with `LP156WF1(TL)(A1)`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you changed the LCD panel, but didn't actually change the Inverter itself.  It's  a separate piece from the LCD panel.

Example pic of inverter:

[image: LCD Inverter]

More types:

[image: more example inverters]

Comment: The inverter is embedded in the lcd panel.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to include the notebook model, the LCD panel you used, etc.   Also, have you taken it apart again and confirmed all connections are connected and seated correctly?

Comment: Ok, I've added the requested data. I've also taken in apart again, yes.